# Como comparar duas listas por propriedade?

Tags: c#, linq

Possuo duas listas de aluno. Gostaria de compará-las pelo atributo Nome, e retornar apenas os valores únicos do aluno01. No exemplo abaixo, retornaria apenas o Aluno01.Nome = "5555".

```
        List<Aluno1> aluno01 = new List<Aluno1>();
        aluno01.Add(new Aluno1 { Id = 1, Nome = "1111" });
        aluno01.Add(new Aluno1 { Id = 2, Nome = "2222" });
        aluno01.Add(new Aluno1 { Id = 2, Nome = "5555" });

        List<Aluno2> aluno02 = new List<Aluno2>();
        aluno02.Add(new Aluno2 { Id = 1, Nome = "1111" });
        aluno02.Add(new Aluno2 { Id = 2, Nome = "2222" });
        aluno02.Add(new Aluno2 { Id = 2, Nome = "3333" });
        aluno02.Add(new Aluno2 { Id = 2, Nome = "4444" });
```

Grato,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar `using System.Linq;`

```
var intersect = aluno01.Where(a => !aluno02.Select(b => b.Nome).Contains(a.Nome));
```

Veja funcionando em [***dotnetfiddle***](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KH8eUo)

Comment: Perfeito, era isso!